# Processing 2: Saving keyboard input as .txt files using timestamp in file name

Tags: text, timestamp, processing, keyboard-events

I'm at the start of an ambitious (for me) project in Processing 2 for my MA in Creative Media.

I want to create a sort of chain novel where users add to a long continuous narrative, but each user's input is saved as an individual text file and printed on separate index cards.

My issue (first of many presumably) is when saving the individual .txt files which are a record of each user's input, I want the filename to contain the timestamp.

I've used
    textFile = createWriter(timestamp+.txt); 
as a placeholder for the moment, but this obviously isn't a 'thing'...

This is what I have so far:

```
//Code adapted from examples by Amnon available here:     https://amnonp5.wordpress.com/2012/01/28/25-life-saving-tips-for-processing/ 
//and Daniel Shiffman available here: http://www.learningprocessing.com/examples/chapter-18/example-18-1/



String myText = "Give me your story.";
String yourText = ""; // Variable to store text currently being typed
String savedText = ""; // Variable to store saved text when control is hit
PrintWriter textFile;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  textSize(30);
  fill(0);
  // Create a new file in the sketch directory
  timestamp = year() + nf(month(),2) + nf(day(),2) + "-"  + nf(hour(),2) + nf(minute(),2) + nf(second(),2);
  textFile = createWriter(timestamp+.txt);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  text(myText, 0, 0, width, height);
  text(yourText, 0, 0, width, height);
  text(savedText, 0, 0, width, height);
{
  textFile.println("savedText");
  textFile.flush();
  textFile.close();
  exit();
 } 
  }

void keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode == ENTER) {
    myText="";}
  if (keyCode == BACKSPACE) {
    if (yourText.length() > 0) {
      yourText = yourText.substring(0, yourText.length()-1);
  }
  } 
  else if (keyCode == DELETE) {
    yourText = "";
  } 
  else if (keyCode != SHIFT && keyCode != CONTROL && keyCode != ALT) {
    yourText = yourText + key;
  }
    // If the Control key is pressed, save the String and clear it
  if (key == CODED) 
  {
    if (keyCode == CONTROL) {
    savedText = yourText;
    // Text is cleared
    yourText = ""; 
  } else {
    // Otherwise, concatenate the String
    // Each character typed by the user is added to the end of the String variable.
    yourText = yourText + key; 
  }
}
}
```

As you can tell I am brand-new to code and what's above is not an elegant piece of code and probably making your eyes bleed. If you have any suggestions for making it better, or a better alternative than timestamp for naming the multiple .txt files, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow and coding in general!

Processing, which is a variation of Java, [is strongly typed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954068/java-strongly-typed-or-weak-typed) meaning that each variable needs to be declared with its proper type, and thus follows its own rules of [predictability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing#Predictability)

The problem shows up at this line:

```
textFile = createWriter(timestamp+.txt);
```

and the accompanying error:

```
unexpected token .
```

If you look at createWriter in [the processing reference](https://processing.org/reference/createWriter_.html) in the Parameters section, it says that it takes in a **String**

The solution is to change your line to this (notice the **""** around .txt):

```
textFile = createWriter(timestamp+".txt");
```

The problem is that, unless you actually define a piece of text as a String in your code, it' wont be treated as a String, rather as a piece of code to be evaluated.

When processing gets to the line and inside the parenthesis of createWriter it finds `timstamp` and `+` and then it finds a dot. What you meant is to just stick the .txt at the end of the timestamp, but unless you define that as a String (like this: `".txt"`) it will not understand that, and will try to evaluate whatever you have there.

In order to understand the difference maybe another example is in order:

Create a new sketch and add this:

```
String s = "one";
println(s + " two");
println(s + " + two");
```

if you run it you will see in the console below two lines appearing:

```
one two
one + two
```

As you can see the first line contains just our variable `s` as well as the string `" two"` (notice the space in the beginning) and the second one contains again the variable `s` and the string `" + two"`.

The main thing to take away from here is that in one case `+` is an operator to concatenate strings, while in the other it is just an actual piece of text we want to use.

Comment: Thanks so much. Petros for the prompt and helpful answer. Will have another go. Thanks again!

Comment: UPDATE: Coming back as 'Cannot find anything named "timestamp".' I wonder is it a discontinued feature in Processing 2?

Comment: FYI figured out the timestamp thing in Processing. First I needed to import the Calendar utility. 'import java.util.Calendar;'
Then before 'Setup' I needed this:
'// timestamp
String timestamp() {
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
return String.format("%1$ty%1$tm%1$td_%1$tH%1$tM%1$tS", now);
}'
That along with Petros' help got it working. Thanks.